# Try-finally block with return doesn't rise exception

Tags: java, exception, try-finally

In this code main method's Catch doesn't catch Runtime exception. after the execution of finally block, it should've gone to the exception block of main, but it doesn't.

```
 class FinallyDemo {
    static int m1(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Inside m1");
            throw new RuntimeException("hi");
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("m1 finally");
            return 5;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.out.println(m1());
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("main caught: "+ e);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Inside m1
m1 finally
5
```

Comment: Are you really getting the mentioned output. As per i know, the `void` method does not return any value. Hence `System.out.println(m1());` will produce compile time exception.

Comment: sorry about that, i have edite the code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(As noted in comments, the code as written wouldn't even compile, but that can be fixed without changing the core of the question.)

> it should've gone to the exception block of main, but it doesn't.

No, it's behaving exactly as the spec [section 14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2). There are lots of paths there, but the ones that are applied here are:

> - ...
> - If execution of the `try` block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V
>
>   - ...
>   - If the run-time type of V is not assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any `catch` clause of the try statement, then the `finally` block is executed
>
>     - ...
>     - If the `finally` block completes abruptly for reason S, then the `try` statement completes abruptly for reason S (and the throw of value V is discarded and forgotten).

A `return` statement counts as "completing abruptly", as per [section 14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1). So the whole try/finally statement completes abruptly for reason of "return with a value", just as if an exception hadn't been thrown.

If you want the exception to propagate beyond the `try`/`finally` statement, don't use a `return` statement in the `finally` block.

Comment: With eclipse at least you also get a warning, that the finally is not completing "normally". Reason was explained perfect in the answer above.

Answer (score -2):

Here is bytecode of this class.

```
static int m1();
    descriptor: ()I
    flags: ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=1, args_size=0
         0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: ldc           #3                  // String Inside m1
         5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: new           #5                  // class java/lang/RuntimeException
        11: dup
        12: ldc           #6                  // String hi
        14: invokespecial #7                  // Method java/lang/RuntimeException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        17: athrow
        18: astore_0
        19: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        22: ldc           #8                  // String m1 finally
        24: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        27: iconst_5
        28: ireturn
      Exception table:
         from    to  target type
             0    19    18   any
```

After review this program.

```
public class FinallyDemo {
    static void m1(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Inside m1");
            throw new RuntimeException("hi");
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("m1 finally");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            m1();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("main caught: "+ e);
        }
    }
}
```

Bytecode.

```
 static void m1();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=1, args_size=0
         0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: ldc           #3                  // String Inside m1
         5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: new           #5                  // class java/lang/RuntimeException
        11: dup
        12: ldc           #6                  // String hi
        14: invokespecial #7                  // Method java/lang/RuntimeException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        17: athrow
        18: astore_0
        19: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        22: ldc           #8                  // String m1 finally
        24: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        27: aload_0
        28: athrow
      Exception table:
         from    to  target type
             0    19    18   any
```

In my opinion, athrow is essentially a jump statement.
Obviously, adding a return statement in finally, the athrow statement is omitted at compile time because it is determined to be unreachable

Comment: If the `athrow` 'statement' was 'omitted at compile time' how did it get into the bytecode?

Comment: I mean throw an exception to the outer stack frame。If  the athrow 'statement' was not  'omitted'.The bytecode should like this.                                                                                   ```27:iconst_5  28:ireturn 29: aload_0 30:athrow```

Comment: So if it wasn't 'omitted' why did you say it was? Make up your mind. The bytecode should look the way it does look, and saying that it should look otherwise isn't an explanation for why it looks, and works, the way it does. And `athrow` is not 'essentially a jump statement': it takes a dozen lines in the JVM Specification to specify what it really does. Your answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: I'm just explaining the reason for the finally 'statement'  discarding  exception. I know athrow works through expection table, I just want to point out that they work through goto rather than interruption mechanisms.(It used to bother me.)